# How do I get a list of parent pages in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I was trying to make a list of all parent pages in wordpress. More specifically, A list of ancestor pages to use as a breadcrumb trail.

I want to get the parent, it's parent, etc. all the way to the top level.

For example, for this page structure:

- Page

  - Subpage

    - Subsubpage

      - Subsubsubpage

Called from Subsubsubpage it should return

- Page
- Subpage
- Subsubpage

And called from Subsubpage it should return

- Page
- Subpage

Answer (score 0):

get_post_ancestors() returns the page id's of all ancestors as an array.

wp_list_pages() accepts a comma seperated list of page ids

The implode() function glues together the array with a string, in this case a comma.

By imploding the results of get_post_ancestors with commas, it effectively creates a comma seperated list of ancestor's page ids to pass to wp_list_pages().

The default usage of wp_list_pages() would create nested lists. Setting the depth option to -1 arranges all items in a flat list.

The last important bit, the if statement checks to make sure the post actually has a parent before listing parent pages. If there are no parents, and get_post_ancestors() is called, it returns all pages on the WP site for some reason or another.

Putting it all together,

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $ancestorsCSV =  implode( ',' , get_post_ancestors( $post));

        if ($post->post_parent){
            wp_list_pages('include='.$ancestorsCSV.'&title_li=&depth=-1' ); 
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I surprisingly wasn't able to find such a solution via google search.

Comment: Actually, this returns them in alphabetical order. Anyone know how to do this and keep the correct order?

Comment: `get_post_ancestors` does **not** return the page ID's of all ancestors, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/, it returns **the** ID(s) of **the** parent page(s) of a given page and hierarchical chain, passed as a Post Object to the method. Useless to get **all** parent pages. 

It can only get all parents of **one hierarchical chain**, directly bound to the Post Objet passed to it.

But those are not **all parent pages**. All parent Pages in fact are all pages without a parent but direct child. Those are the utmost parent pages.

Comment: get_post_ancestors does get all the ids of all the parent pages, you can see that in the link you referenced. This was for a breadcrumb "I want to get the parent, it's parent, etc. all the way to the top level." so get_post_ancestors was as appropriate 9 years ago as it is today.